# Display references in alphabetic order of authors in bibliography.

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am using `\bibliography{Temp_Bib}` command to import reference entries in my report. In Temp_Bib.bib file I keep the BibTex entries of cited articles. I am using `\cite{Keyword}` to cite an entry from my bibliography file. When I use latex2pdf then the entries of bibliography section shown in the order in which they are called by `\cite` command.

So is there any way in which I can display the entries in my bibliography with the sorted manner of authors second name?

Right now no matter what I put the bibtex entries, they are displayed in the order in which they are cited in report. I want that in whatever order they are cited; they should be display according to authors name in sorted manner.

Comment: do not use the bibliographystyle `unsrt`. Use style `plain` or `alpha` instead

Comment: Thanks.. but which style I should use so references will be displayed in sorted according to authors last name.

Comment: what documentclass do you have? And do you have a command `\bibliographystyle{...}`?

Comment: I am using `\documentclass{llncs}` and `\bibliographystyle{alpha}`. By this I am able to get references in sorted order according to author names. But they are numbered like [AB05]... [AF07]... And I need it like [1]... [2]... Any suggestions...!

Comment: then use `\bibliographystyle{plain}`

Comment: @Herbert could you add an answer so we can get this off the `unanswered` tab?

Answer (score 1):

Are you supposed not to use biblatex as a package?
Otherwise I strongly advise you to do so, since it is quite easy to choose the sorting option of the bibliography, whatever the style of bibliography you are using.